# Adding Optional Elements in a new WSDL version

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am exposing a webservice with multiple versions - 1,2,3 and 4.I have to include a new optional element in 4th version of the webservice. Even though I have different versions of endpoint , all point to the same implementation logic. When I map the values to optional element introduced in 4th version , should I add a check in the implementation logic to ensure that value is mapped only if the request is hitting the 4th version of endpoint? If I do not add such a check , my implementation logic will map the element to newly added element for requests coming in via all the endpoints. Will this result in any exception since other WSDLs do not have the optional element in response or will it work fine since it is an optional element?

Answer (score 0):

If the client side is doing any sort of schema validation against the web service response and your response data does not conform to the version of the schema that the client is using, an exception on the client side is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response.In my case , the WSDL that the client is consuming will not change. But will there be any be impact on the server (service) side , if data is mapped to newly added elements and newly added elements are not present in old WSDL versions.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your implementation, I don't really know if this will result in an error or not.  Have you tried it?

Comment: It results in marshallingexception , but I just wanted to check if it is expected.